# Comment / URL shortener message shows tags

Tags: bug, comments, url-shortener

I tried to add a link shortened with bitly to my comment, and received the following error message.

What I noticed about it is that it has HTML tags visible (`<br>`, `<b>`, etc.)

I'm assuming this is a bug.

[image]

Comment: Error messages cannot contain that content. Please avoid using HTML tags; they can break without leaving any useful...

Comment: Maybe you are supposed to interpret the markup in your brain. Did you try doing that?

Comment: It would be a lot better if you included both links in your post.

Comment: http://bit.ly/3hDSUb - Apparently allowed here?

Comment: @PeterB, your link is incorrect, it should be https://bit.ly/18gECvy

Comment: Or, is it https://bit.ly/2Brp3YC? @DidierL

Comment: @DidierL I'm very disappointed that your link wasn't a rickroll, and was instead useful information. Now nobody's going to click on it, because they'll all expect it to be a rickroll, when it isn't.